# Selenium-webdriver cannot find element using CSS selector

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I used selenium-webdriver js. I tryed to input value in the field.
test.js:

```
async () => {
  let driver = await new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
  try {
    await driver.get("http://test.com");
     await driver.findElement(By.id('user')).sendKeys("test", Key.RETURN);
  }catch (e) {    
     console.log(e);
  } finally {
     await driver.quit();
  }
}
```

But console displaed error:

```
NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[id="user"]"}
(Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.163)
```

I don't understand why this error appear. Because desired field looks like this:

```
<input placeholder="User Name" type="text" id="user" class="input" value="">
```

What can I do with this problem?

Comment: Check if the element present inside an iframe?

Comment: @KunduK, There is simple element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [wait](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_WebDriver.html#wait) to wait [until](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.html) your element is being located on the page.

```
 await driver.get("http://test.com");

 // add the following line to wait for the element to be present on the page
 await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('user')));

 await driver.findElement(By.id('user')).sendKeys("test", Key.RETURN);
```

Comment: Without an explanation it is hard to understand if and why this answers the question. Please edit your answer to make it more clear.

Comment: @TalZ, ok, thnx